# What would have happened if DART failed to hit Didymoon?

Tags: dart

So I remember reading that there was a 10% chance DART will not hit Didymoon. It was on the German Wikipedia, but without a source.

Now, I'm wondering if there would have been any plans if DART failed to hit the asteroid. I can imagine this being a very big problem because DART's propellant might not have been enough + the limited lifetime of LiciaCube.

Looking forward to your insights!

Comment: What do you mean by "propellant might not have been enough"? Not hitting an asteroid doesn't need any propellant.

Comment: Well, nothing would have happened

Comment: Isn't the target Dimorphos?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Didymoon is a widely used informal name for Dimorphos.

Comment: There have been many failed space missions. The answer to the question is simple: DART would have become yet another one of those failed space missions had it failed to hit Dimorphos. The vehicle had enough propellant for one attempt, and that's it.

Comment: @asdfex Propellant is needed to steer and adjust trajectory. If, for example, if they noticed that the asteroid wasn't where they calculated it as being, they would've required a course change and if they didn't have enough propellant onboard to execute this change, the mission would've failed.

Comment: @Dragongeek RAD seems to ask about what would have happend if impact failed. So, is the question what had happened if they missed it, or how much they could correct the trajectory during the approach?